# CameraX Preview, Analysis use cases image size versus Capture use case [android]

Tags: android, android-camera2

## Introduction

After going through the couple source of information

- [CameraX overview android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)
- [CameraX get started codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0)

I set up a class, called `CameraProxy`,  using a Builder design pattern to encapsulate use cases configuration and set/reset function required to configure and set camera lifecycle. The objective of this code refactoring is code reuse.

The instance of `CameraProxy` is created from the `MainActivity` of the app. The objective of this code is to be able to do "real time" (as much as the app can provide it) image processing. My understanding is that the image processing could be performed by the analysis use case or the capture use case (in memory). The thing is that the 2 use cases (capture, analysis) do not provide the same input image size.

I will first describe the code, describe the problem I have and finally formulate questions.

## Code

### CameraProxy - creating use cases and setting up the camera life cycle

```
    class CameraProxy private constructor()
    {
        class Builder(var cameraView: TextureView, var parentActivity: AppCompatActivity, var executor: ExecutorService)
        {
            var imagePreviewUseCase: Preview?= null
                private set
            var imageCaptureUseCase: ImageCapture?= null
                private set
            var imageAnalysisUseCase: ImageAnalysis?= null
                private set

            //default surface texture is from the codelab example - but this was chagned to use aspect ration (by the way the 640/480 is RATIO_4_3)
            fun addPreview(width: Int = 640, height: Int = 480) = apply {
                val config = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
                    //setTargetResolution(Size(width, height))
                    setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                }.build()

                imagePreviewUseCase = Preview(config)

                imagePreviewUseCase?.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
                    // To update the SurfaceTexture, we have to remove it and re-add it
                    val parent = cameraView.parent as ViewGroup
                    // release the last surface texture
                    parent.removeView(cameraView)
                    // set the new surface texture
                    parent.addView(cameraView, 0)

                    cameraView.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
                }

                // Exceeding capability of target camera device will throw an IllegalArgumentException
                //CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imagePreviewUseCase)
            }

            fun addCapture(useMaxQuality: Boolean = false) = apply {
                val config = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
                    .apply {
                        // We don't set a resolution for image capture; instead, we
                        // select a capture mode which will infer the appropriate
                        // resolution based on aspect ratio and requested mode
                        // MAX_QUALITY and MIN_LATENCY
                        val capMode: ImageCapture.CaptureMode = if (useMaxQuality) {
                            ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY
                        } else {
                            ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY
                        }
                        setCaptureMode(capMode)
                    }.build()

                // Build the image capture use case
                imageCaptureUseCase = ImageCapture(config)

                // Currently up to 3 use cases may be bound to a Lifecycle at any time.
                // Exceeding capability of target camera device will throw an IllegalArgumentException
                //CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imageCaptureUseCase)
            }

            // ImageAnalysis.Analyzer is an interface
            fun addAnalysis(a: ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, useNext: Boolean = false) = apply {
                val config = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
                    val mode: ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode = if (useNext) {
                        ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_NEXT_IMAGE
                    } else {
                        ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE
                    }
                    setImageReaderMode(mode)
                }.build()

                imageAnalysisUseCase = ImageAnalysis(config).apply {
                    setAnalyzer(executor, a)
                }

                // Currently up to 3 use cases may be bound to a Lifecycle at any time.
                // Exceeding capability of target camera device will throw an IllegalArgumentException
                //CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imageAnalysisUseCase)
            }

            fun build() : CameraProxy
            {
                var doPreview: Boolean = (imagePreviewUseCase!=null)
                var doCapture: Boolean = (imageCaptureUseCase!=null)
                var doAnalysis: Boolean = (imageAnalysisUseCase!=null)

                when {
                    doPreview && doAnalysis && doCapture
                                ->   CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imagePreviewUseCase,imageAnalysisUseCase,imageCaptureUseCase)
                    doAnalysis && doCapture
                                ->   CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imageAnalysisUseCase, imageCaptureUseCase)
                    doPreview && doAnalysis
                                ->   CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imagePreviewUseCase,imageAnalysisUseCase)
                    doPreview && doCapture
                                ->   CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imagePreviewUseCase,imageCaptureUseCase)
                    doPreview
                                ->   CameraX.bindToLifecycle(parentActivity, imagePreviewUseCase)
                    else -> CameraX.unbindAll()
                }
                return CameraProxy()
            }

        }//Builder
    } // CameraProxy
```

An alternate implementation of `CameraProxy` would consist in setting use cases 'on the fly' just after being created (as an example these lines calling `CameraX.bindToLifecycle()` are commented in `addCapture()`, `addPreview()` and `addAnalysis()` method). The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases) stipulates it is better to set use cases all at a time so that the best compromise for aspect ratio, target resolution and device hardware capability can be found. The `build()` method makes a single call to `CameraX.bindToLifecycle()` taking into account supported configuration combination. For me, using one or the other implementation did not change anything with regards to the problem I am writting this question.

### The application and its uses cases

The app has a very simple UI with a `TextureView` (`camera_view` id), an `ImageButton` (`capture_button` id)  and and `TextView` (`text_result_view` is).

The app activity creates the camera life cycle in the `onCreate()` event handler.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        // SurfaceTexture to map video display
        private lateinit var cameraView: TextureView
        // Button with a background image
        private lateinit var captureButton: ImageButton
        private lateinit var textResultView: TextView

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            cameraView = findViewById(R.id.camera_view)
            captureButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.capture_button)
            textResultView= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_result_view)

            // check and request camera permissions if necessary
            managePermissions()
                            .....
                            cameraView.post { startCamera() }

            // Every time the provided texture view changes rotateLayout is called
            cameraView.addOnLayoutChangeListener{  v,  left,  top,  right,  bottom, oldLeft,  oldTop,  oldRight,  oldBottom ->
                if(v is TextureView) {
                    // automatic cast from View to TextureView
                    onCameraViewLayoutChange(v)
                }
            }
            captureButton.setOnClickListener(){ _ -> onCaptureButtonClick() }
        }
        ....
        private lateinit var cameraProxy:CameraProxy
        private lateinit var executor:ExecutorService
        private var  imageCapture:ImageCapture?= null       
        private fun startCamera()
        {
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
            var cameraProxy:CameraProxy=
                CameraProxy.Builder(cameraView,this,executor)
                    .addPreview()
                    .addAnalysis(LuminosityAnalyzer())
                    .addCapture()
                    .apply {
                        /**
                         * @Todo
                         *  imageCaptureUseCase should stay in Builder as a private property
                         */
                        imageCapture=this.imageCaptureUseCase
                    }
                    .build()
```

for the purpose of the capture use case (similar to what is explained in the [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#6)) `CaptureSavedImageInMemory`  implements `ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener` interface. The `onCaptureButtonClick()` is the captureButton button event listerner callback ( in `MainActivity`)

```
        ....
        fun onCameraViewLayoutChange(v:View)
        {
        ....
        }
        class CaptureSavedImageInMemory : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener()
        {
        ....
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy?, rotationDegrees: Int) 
            {
            }
        ....
        }

        fun onCaptureButtonClick(){
            //in memory image cpature
            imageCapture?.takePicture(executor,CaptureSavedImageInMemory())
        }
```

For the purpose of the analysis use case (similar to what is explained in the [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#7)) `LuminosityAnalyzer` implements `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` interface. The analysis processing is actually done in `analysis()` method.

```
        ....
        inner private class class LuminosityAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer 
        {
        ....
            override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int)
            {
            ....
            }       
        }
        ....
    }
```

## Problems

### Problem with ImageProxy size

the image proxy have different size in the capture use case in fun `CaptureSavedImageInMemory.onCaptureSuccess()` and in the analysis use case in fun `LuminosityAnalyzer.analyze()`  .

In the capture use case I get image sizes according to the camera default setting 4608 x 3456 (aspect ratio is 4/3).

In the analysis use case I get image matching the surface texture size actually 640 x 480 as set in the UI editor. It does not change anything whether the Preview use case is built setting target resolution nor aspect ratio.

### Problem with the Preview

the preview does not preserve the aspect ratio. It is not 4/3 as set in the configuration. In addition The image is cropped into the surface texture

## Questions

### Question w/r ImageProxy size / resolution

how could I get the same resolution for image proxy in capture and analysis uses cases ?

### aspect ratio and image display resize for the Preview

how can I resize the video stream to fit the surface texture and preserve the image ratio.  I d like to display the stream into a 640x480 and scale the image down  whilst keeping the 4/3 aspect ratio.

### Joker question

how better is CameraX API over camera2 API ?

Comment: as for image proxy resolution this can be handled while configuring the uses cases. Each use cas configuration can control target resolution and/or (this is not clear what strategy is implemented) aspect ratio.

Comment: binding use cases **all at once** or **individually** results in different image  width and height in the capture w/r to analysis. If all set together `ImageProxy` argument in `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer.analysis()` and `ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener.onCaptureSuccess()` are similar and bound to the preview surface texture. While set individually, the image proxy can be decoupled from the preview in capture use case. Analysis will invariably have the same image width and height similar to the preview use case. Also the image is clipped in analysis has displayed in the preview.